# Android, why I cant call my stringarray inside a method outside of onCreate?

Tags: java, android, arrays, oop, oncreate

Outside my onCreate method my stringarray isnt able to be called , why is that ?

I tried to initialize the stringarray again in the method outside onCreate with getResources(); but I cant call that either,
 im guessing there is some fundemental knowledge im lacking as im fairly new in the programming world, can u help me or explain why the string array can't be called outside onCreate and/or how to work around it ?

example inside onCreate :

```
final String[] list = res.getStringArray(R.array.fact);
```

outside onCreate :

```
public void facts(){
   getResources();
final String[] list = res.getStringArray(R.array.fact);

}// marked res. in red saying "qualifier must be an expression" and without that I cant call "list"..
```

Comment: How do you expect a sensible answer without you sharing your code?

Comment: I dont think my code is needed for the question, since its more a general question

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is **variable scope**.  You've declared your string array in the onCreate() method, giving it "method scope" and then you're tying to access it in another method.  I would suggest declaring your string array as a class level variable so that you can access it from any method within that class.

To avoid the `NullPointerException` issue pointed out by Ben P. in a comment, you could initialize your array variable in the onResume() method so that you have it ready to go before you need to use it anywhere else.

Make sure to take a look at the reference links below the code example.  I think they'll help explain "why" better than I can in a quick answer here.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String[] list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // onResume() runs after onCreate() and onStart() in the Android Activity lifecycle.
        // If your array has not been initialized yet, do it now.
        if (list == null || list.length == 0) {
            list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fact);
        }
    }

    public void facts() {
        // Do something with your array...
        for (String arrayItem : list) {
            String fact = arrayItem.toUpperCase();
        }
    }

}
```

**References:**

- The Activity Lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
- Variable scope: https://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
final String[] list = res.getStringArray(R.array.fact);
```

by

```
final String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fact);
```

Comment: Do not do this for class-level fields. `getResources()` doesn't return a valid `Resources` object until after `onCreate()` has executed, so this code will throw a `NullPointerException`. Doing this inside other methods that execute after `onCreate()` is fine.